# Unable to create a grouping in Apache Kylin

Tags: apache, olap, cube, kylin

Hello I am running Apache Kylin apachekylin/apache-kylin-standalone:3.0.0-alpha2 Docker image

I started out by creating two Hive tables one to record store sales and one consisting of store metadata

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS STORESALES (
id INT,
food FLOAT,
drugs FLOAT,
cosmetic FLOAT,
baby FLOAT,
reportdate DATE);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS STOREMETA (
id INT,
address STRING,
brand STRING,
owner STRING);
```

I then created a model in which I declared **STORESALES** as my fact table and **STOREMETA** as a lookup table with left join `STORESALES.ID = STOREMETA.ID`
I then declare

- STOREMETA.ID
- STOREMETA.ADDRESS
- STOREMET.OWNER
- STOREMETA.BRAND

as dimensions.  I explicitly deleted **STORESALES.ID** I also specify measures

- STORESALES.DRUGS
- STORESALES.BABY
- STORESALES.COMSETICS
- STORESALES.FOOD

[image: Here's what the model looks like]

and also specified **STORESALES.REPORTDATE** as my partition

So then I go on to set up my cube.  Again I add **STOREMETA[ID, BRAND, OWNER, NAME]** as dimensions, but for some reason **STOREDATA.ID** shows up as a choice for a dimension as well.  I add measures as **MAX_FOOD**, **MAX_DRUGS**, **MAX_COSMETICS**, **MAX_BABY**.  The issues is once I get to Advanced Settings the only options for grouping available are **STORESALES.ID**.  If I manually enter anything else it disappears from the list.  I went back to edit the model and noticed that **STORESALES.ID** is now in the list of measures as well.

[image: STORESALES.ID is back]

Not sure if this is what breaking things for me.  Or if my general lack of experience here is hindering my progress.  Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issues is that by default all dimensions in a cube are considered to be derived.  That is derived is is selected when I select a measure.  It looks like a grouping cannot be created with derived dimensions.

Comment: Hopefully this helps someone, I am not an experienced Data Warehousing person, and I did not find anything in the manual that explained it

Comment: Hi there is a statement on "normal" and "derived" in the tutorial (https://kylin.apache.org/docs/tutorial/create_cube.html), but I agree with you that it is not clear enough, especially for the new users. Do you think whether it can help if we add some more statements for what it really means?

Comment: @ShaoFengShi I think it would be very helpful to link from the step-by-step tutorial to pertinent sections of the "Technical Concepts" doc.  However the most complete description of a derived type seems to be in http://kylin.apache.org/docs/howto/howto_optimize_cubes.html.  So maybe just a matter of restructuring the doc